# Import/export data in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export, dump

I have a db on my localhost. I also have the same db on live hosting which I need to update. 
For example, I have a table1 and table2.
In table1 I added new column "price":null, in table2 I added few rows with data.
Live tables may be more up-to-dated then local ones and may contain more 
I need to make a dump file to update my live db:

1. for table1: only the structure,
2. for table2: only the data.

How can I do it with phpmyadmin? I'm afraid to lost the date because of flag "drop table/create table". Without this flag it cause error "table already exists"

Answer (score 0):

you can do these:

1) Remove these drop table codes from your dump file:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
```

2) Add "IF NOT EXISTS" to your Create statement so that it does not re-create table1 if table1 exists.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` {
...
}
```